# What clause element is this please?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses, syntax, subordinate-clauses, adverbial-phrases

> When she got into the car at five, **ready for the fifteen-mile drive across London**, it wouldn't start.

What does this stretch of language represent? Is it an adverbial?

Answer (score 1):

Sample sentence:
When she got into the car at five, ready for the fifteen-mile drive across London, it wouldn't start.

The phrase describes what state or condition she was in. It is not a clause.

It functions like an appositive adjective, but is phrasal.

> [appositive adjective](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-appositive-adjective-1688999)
>
> An Appositive Adjective is a traditional grammatical term for an
>   adjective (or a series of adjectives) that follows a noun and, like a
>   nonrestrictive appositive, is set off by commas or dashes.

Comment: Thanks, which word does it modify then, please? I think it modifies "she", but it does not follow it directly, so I am confused.

Comment: @PetrKment Arguably, it could also be acting adverbially, describing *how* she got into the car ("in readiness for"). But it's ambiguous. (However, it acting adjectivally is more likely because of how it's constructed: "she was ready.") There is no reason why it can't modify *her* adjectivally—there's no rule that says something *must* come immediately after something else.

Comment: ready has to describe a person or state. An adjective does not modify a personal pronoun.  You can't really say: a ready she. She was ready.

Comment: Well some adjectives can go strictly before nouns and some strictly after them, right? Adjectives can modify personal pronouns. In addition, "she" is a syntactic noun in this case, I believe. "Ready" is an adjective that can only follow the word it modifies, it cannot precede it.

Comment: @PetrKment "I think it modifies she". There is no such thing. Why are you arguing about that? Adjectives do not modify these personal pronouns: I, you, he, she, it, we, they. The phrase with ready is in apposition to: "she got into her car".It can also be a truncated and implied: She got into her car [and was] ready for x. There are several ways to look at it. In other words, an implied compound predicate. get into the car and be ready.

Comment: Okay :) I am just a student of syntax,  sorry. Learning new things every day.

Answer (score 0):

Since OP mentions the fact that the phrase does not "follow...directly" the pronoun it appears to modify, consider the following:

> Before she took a bite of the shoe, hungry as can be, she said grace.

Do not imagine yourself to be a naive parsing algorithm.  Clearly any sane human being would know that shoes do not experience hunger (at least in this universe), and would understand that **hungry as can be** must modify **she**, not **the shoe**.

Answer (score 0):

> *When she got into the car at five, **ready for the fifteen-mile drive**
>   **across London**, it wouldn't start.*

The element in bold is a predicative adjunct: predicative because it refers to a predicand ("she") and an adjunct because it's an optional modifier in clause structure, i.e. it's part of the VP, not the subject NP "she".

I think it might be misleading to call it 'adverbial', though 'adjunct' is really just a more appropriate term for many of the items that traditional grammar calls 'adverbial'.

Comment: Since it implies [and she was ready], call it an adjunct but it's most definitely adjectival.

Comment: Of course it's an AdjP, that's why it qualifies as predicative. But it's located in the VP, not the subject NP, which is why it's called a predicative adjunct. I made that **very** clear in my answer.